# Electric Potential: Building system of point charges

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, coulombs-law, conservative-field

How can we prove that the amount of work we have to do to build a system of point charges is same , whether we place the point charges one by one or all at once

Answer (score 0):

Like any central force, electrostatic force is a [conservative force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force). This means that the force is the negative gradient of an electrostatic potential energy that depends only on the positions of the charges. The work is thus independent of the path between two configurations and simply equal to the change in the potential energy between the configurations.